# Python: reading an overflowing file

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

I'm trying to read a large data file using python. The file is output from some Fortran code that I am running. However, due to a large number of cells, the data has 'spilled' across multiple lines.[see image to be a bit more clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mscy9.png).

I've been trying to read this using `np.loadtxt` but this raises the error that `ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 2`. I'm fairly sure this is because the data is badly formatted. For reference, I want to output an array that's ultimately going to be (1000 rows x 2000 columns). Is there a way to get numpy to understand that my array should in fact have 2000 columns, so it can read in the data file?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could preprocess that file into an intermediate file that is fixed for numpy and then read it. If its consistently 2 lines to 1 line that would be easy to do. Scrubbing cruddy data is all part of the job.

Comment: Are you okay with NaNs in your data? Because you CAN read that in. If you specify an array of columns when reading it in in pandas it will read those columns and fill in NaNs. But if you have weird line terminations and the like it'll still be tough.